# getAttribute("gltf-model") returns the directory path

Tags: aframe

I have gltf entity in my script

```
<a-asset-item id="tree" src="/path/to/tree.gltf"></a-asset-item>
<a-entity gltf-model="#tree"></a-entity>
```

when I use getAttribute("gltf-model"), it returns /path/to/tree.gltf. How can I make it return the id instead of the directory path?